# Find max value in std::vector of structure of specified variable

Tags: c++, vector, max

I have vector of structure described below:

```
struct Point {
    double x,y;
};
```

And now I have `vector<Point>` which contains about 2000 elements. I want to find element which contains maximum value of variable `y` in `Point`.

I know there is std::max_element but I don't know if it works with variables stored in structures inside vector.

Comment: [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element)

Comment: I was considering to leave a snarky comment along the line of "please read some documentation" but I decided to write an answer, nevertheless... please read some documentation ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't know if it works with variables stored in structures inside vector.

Yes it does. Use a custom comparator:

```
auto it = std::max_element(v.begin(),
                           v.end(),
                           [](const auto& a,const auto& b) { 
                               return a.y < b.y; 
                           });
```

Comment: I would use : auto it = std::max_element(v.begin(),v.end(),[](**const auto&** a, **const auto&** b) { return a.y < b.y; }); const because content of struct shouldn't be changed. And & because we don't need copies of the struct either.